# Items on desktop all disappered, including my Home, from icon list

Tags: unity, 16.04, icons, home-directory

After logging in on my Ubuntu 16.04 my documents and shortcuts have all disappeared from desktop, even my Home icon is missing,can't even right-click on desktop to create any new folder or doc. Searched for home on dash - shows the file, but opening any folder takes me to Disk Usage Analyzer.

Cannot open any folders.

Is there any setting to undo this?

Comment: What happened (or what did you) prior to that? It seems to be something related to permissions...

Comment: Can't remember exactly what i did to mess up, but yesterday had installed java JDK 8, got some errors but was successful.  Thought that might be the problem so had it re installed java jre version 7 now, still the same problem. Any option to make all setting and permissions to default.

Comment: What desktop environment are u using?

Comment: i am using GNOME @user3892683 .  And for the above command its shows E: Unable to locate package gksudo. Also as soon as i coonect my hard disk it takes me to Disk Usage Analyzer. Cant even open the folders inside HD.

Comment: try `su -` and then open natulis from terminal

Comment: Problem solved by running **sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus` This command could also work on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu when "opening any folder takes me to Disk Usage Analyzer".